# Android connect with servlet simple example

Tags: java, android, servlets

I know this question existed, but I really couldn't found any problem while running of the program. I'm try to receive the "Hello Android !!!" text from the servlet and display it by using `Log.i()`.

*Note I am using Android Studio and java servlet.*

This will be trigger while the `button.onClick()` , I tried both Method 1 and Method 2.

Method 1:

```
            try {
                InputStream stream = null;

                URL url = new URL ("http://xxx/HelloWorldServlet");
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setRequestProperty("loginId", mUsername.getText().toString());
                connection.setRequestProperty("password", mPassword.getText().toString());

                try {

                    HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
                    httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    httpConnection.connect();

                    if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                        stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
                    }



                    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                    String s = "";
                    while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null)
                    {Log.i(TAG, s);}

                    ((HttpURLConnection) connection).disconnect();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }         
        }
```

Method 2 :

```
InputStream is = null;

            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://xxx/xxx/mobileapps/HelloWorldServlet");

                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                // Starts the query
                conn.connect();

                int response = conn.getResponseCode();
                Log.d(TAG, "The response is: " + response);
                is = conn.getInputStream();

                String contentAsString = is.toString() ;
                conn.disconnect();

                Log.i(TAG, contentAsString);
            }catch (Exception e) {}
```

Servlet Code:

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    /**
     * Servlet implementation class HelloWorldServlet
     */
    @WebServlet("/HelloWorldServlet")
    public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public HelloWorldServlet() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
         HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
                PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                out.println("Hello Android !!!!");
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

[This is what I get after button triggered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zqo4A.png)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html
You have to do the networking in a thread, not as you did.

Comment: What do you mean so ? Do you mean i should do a throw NetworkOnMainThreadException instead of Exception ? @RanSh

Comment: What they mean is that your code must create a thread separate from the main thread in which the networking code executes, not in the main thread. Like you shouldn't execute other (potentially slow or blocking) code in the UI thread.